# Kafka Json consumer error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, jackson-databind

I'm using spring boot to run kafka consumer with Json Deserializer. When running the application I'm getting the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.createContextual(EnumDeserializer.java:211)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handlePrimaryContextualization(DeserializationContext.java:836)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:550)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:644)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:539)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:644)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:539)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:654)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._prefetchRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:2430)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.<init>(ObjectReader.java:194)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._newReader(ObjectMapper.java:780)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerFor(ObjectMapper.java:4263)
                at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.initialize(JsonDeserializer.java:502)
                at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.setupTarget(JsonDeserializer.java:487)
                ... 56 common frames omitted
```

I'm using spring-boot 3.0.5 and jackson-databing 2.15.0. Has anyone faced with the same error?

I have tried to debug the problem and it seems to be realted to the fact that my domain object contains Enum type as a property. Jackson scans the structure of the object and eagerly loads deserializer for each type, it fails when reaches the enum type. Does anyone have an idea how I could track and solve the problem?

Comment: Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0`

Answer (score 10):

Looks like it was released in `2.15.0` going by this [thread on github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3637).

Adding this `'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.0'` to dependencies fixes it. Credit to @Wenod for pointing it out.

Comment: `jackson-annotations` alone didn't help me, it threw another error, I had to add `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core` too.

Answer (score 4):

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE

It looks like you, somehow, have an older version of jackson-annotations jar on the class path; it should be the same version as the databind jar.

That is a new enum value in `JsonFormat.Feature`:

```java
   /**
     * Override for <code>DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE</code>,
     * which allows unknown Enum values to be ignored and a predefined value specified through
     * {@link com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonEnumDefaultValue @JsonEnumDefaultValue} annotation.
     *
     * @since 2.15
     */
    READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE,
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and getting the same error when I used jackson-databind to serialize and deserialize java enum and it seesm that all 2.15.x have the same issue . the only way to gid rid of this is to return to any 2.14. version
For example the issue gone when I downgraded the vesrion to be as follow

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <jackson-databind.version>2.14.3</jackson-databind.version>
    </properties>

    <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

Also , it seems that reported https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3637 is something related